# How to do a conditionnal view in VueJS with the data?

Tags: vue.js

I would like to show a button just if my data isAdmin is true (using v-if). But it looks like if it doesn't take the value of my isAdmin in the data which I get from the localStorage (I checked, there is the good value inside the data).
So maybe there is an other way to do that... I had a look but I can't find for now.

Here is my code :

````
<div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn-submit-color my-2" v-if="isAdmin === true" v-on:click="deletePost" >Supprimer l'article</button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Post',
  data() { 
      return {
          isAdmin: '',
      }
      },
  mounted(){
      //Modérateur 
      this.isAdmin = localStorage.getItem('isAdmin');
      console.log(this.isAdmin)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isAdmin === true` also checks for type and expects isAdmin to be boolean. Could you confirm that the type of data is also boolean? Depending on your browser, localstorage will store your data in the form of strings, therefore 'true' === true will in fact be false.

Comment: It was exactly the issue, I thought I checked that already but it seems like if I did not, thank you very much !